# Ajax Posts unexpected datatype

Tags: php, ajax

I have been bumping my head with this code few hours now..

Extracting SQL records and making a remove button foreach:

```
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);

          $html.= <a onclick='return Delete($row[id])' href='javascript:void(0)' title='Remove this record'>Remove</a>
}
```

and here comes trouble:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
           function Delete(id)

            {
              if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')==true)

                $.ajax({

                   type: 'POST',
                   url: 'delete.php',
                   data: id,

                   success: function (data) {

                   }
                  });

             }
  </script>
```

So far so good but when I do

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

inside delete.php to check out what information I am getting instead of `ID(INT)` I am getting :

> array(1) {   ["formatMoney"]=>   string(4) "0,00"

NOTE: I tried to set up the dataType as: "string" but got the same effect.

I guess I am doing something wrong. If anyone could point me into the right direction. I would be really grateful.

Comment: Try this:-  data: {id:id}, on server get id as <?php  echo $_POST["id"];//here you get id  ?> and also before send ajax request checK id by alert in the starting of function

Comment: Oh thank you. This fixed it. Could you put it as an answer so I can mark it if anyone bumps into an issue like that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
data: {id:id},
```

on server get id as

```
<?php echo $_POST["id"];//here you get id ?>
```

and also before send ajax request checK id by alert in the starting of function

```
function Delete(id)
{
    alert(id)
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')==true)
}
```